# Format output of specific field in loop if value is equal to XYZ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to re-format the output of a specific value in my iteration. For example, some of my results have values in seconds, the others are text-strings.

Have tried something like this but it's formatting all the values.

How can I iterate through the results, and format the value IF the name = "XYZ"

```
  - for groupreply in 
  @group.groupreply
    %tr 
      %td
        %h4
          = groupreply.attribute_name
      %td
        - if groupreply.attribute_name = "Maximum-Data-Rate-Downstream"
          = groupreply.value.to_i / 1024
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a assignment operator '=' instead of the comparison operator '==' in your if statement. Is it just a typo in posting to stack overflow?

Comment: Sorry, thats just a typo. Wrote code in to remove unnecessary junk.